# Pymongo throws replica set error in ubuntu production server

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, flask, uwsgi

I having troubles in deploying my python flask app to ubuntu 20.04,

[my logs screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLMK5.png)

[my configuration ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJuYo.png)

[my requirements.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO2bN.png)

I worked by this tutorial : [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

some ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your issue will be with your connection string you pass to MongoClient. Make sure the client can connect to the server and is using the correct server address, port, etc.